# Serializing POJOs to XML using jursey + jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb, jackson

I have a pojo class that wants to serialize to an XML request, I have done that using JAXB but couldn't find a way to serialize nested elements.

pojo class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class StudentBean {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    @XmlElement
    public void setFirstName(String fname) {
        this.firstName = fname;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
 // other getters  and setter
```

and i want the XML request as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student>
 <id>123</id>
 <name>
  <firstName> fname </firstName>
  <lastName> lname </lastName>
 </name>
 <age>12</age>
</student>
```

So what are the ways serialize the xml request as above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your XML and see each direct child as a typed object, Student has Three children:

```
XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class StudentBean {

    private int id;
    private Name name;
    private int age;

    // getters & setters
```

you will need to Create Name:

```
public class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters & setters
```

Comment: https://github.com/jasonray/jersey-starterkit/wiki/serializing-a-pojo-to-xml-or-json-using-jaxb
Used this method (same as your answer) and it worked!